# ufw doesn't respect default incoming policy

Tags: networking, 16.04, firewall, ufw, amazon-ec2

I have `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` installed on `EC2` instance.

````
```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp (Nginx HTTPS)      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```
````

I have some service running on the port `4000` and I can access it from the internet, **how it is possible if the only open ports are `443` and `22`?**

Comment: Maybe the service is connecting to you (outgoing) instead of you connecting to it (incoming)?

Comment: @SuperSluether can you elaborate? When I add policy in EC2 `Inbound` it works. But I don't want to use Amazon features to be able to move easily away from it in the future.

Comment: Outgoing is when the server initiates the connection, incoming is when a client initiates the connection. Theoretically, your service could be actively trying to connect to your device, rather than your device trying to connect to the server. Since it works as expected with EC2's firewall, that's obviously not the case here.